# How to convert html code to string in react

Tags: reactjs

I have array of names. I want to make bold for first name. It is not always for only index=0. I have different case where later the second name might need to be bold. I am trying to convert html code to string. But, when I try to print it on screen, I just get {names[0]}  with b tags.

```
const names=["First", "second", "third"];
names[0] = `<b>{names[0]}</b>`;

return names.map(name=><span>{name}</span>);
```

Answer (score 1):

React by default [escapes](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks) all strings to prevent XSS attacks.

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is really dangerous and shouldn't be used if name comes from user input.

Easy solution is wrap the first item by `<b>` JSX tag

```
const names = ["First", "second", "third"];

return names.map((name, index) => (
  <span>{index === 0 ? <b>{name}</b> : name}</span>
));
```

Comment: It is not always for only index=0.

Comment: @Laxmichandana If you know which index it should be, dynamically change zero to desired number

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, otherwise it will be just seen as mere text.

You can read more about this React attribute in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml.

An example is:

```js
function createMarkup() {
const names=["First", "second", "third"];
names[0] = `<b>{names[0]}</b>`;

  return {__html: names.map(name=><span>{name}</span>)};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Where in `createMarkup` you write in the stuff you had and then render it as shown in `myComponent`.

Comment: I am getting error has '{__html: JSX.Element[]} is not assignable to type '{__html: string;}'. at div tag

Comment: Try to call the array method `toString()` like so: `names.map(name=><span>{name}</span>).toString()`. This converts the array to `string` which is basically what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to convert HTML to string is not the best way to go about this. Here is a better way to achieve this:

```
return (
<div>
  {names.map((name, i) => (
    <span style={{ fontWeight: i === 0 ? "bold" : "normal" }}>{name}</span>
  ))}
</div>
```

);

`i` is the index of the array element in the `map` loop. This will make the text bold only if `i === 0`

Comment: It is not always for only index=0.